# Starting IIS Express from command line asp.net mvc 3 project (build with VS2012)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, command-line, visual-studio-2012, iis-express

I have an asp.net mvc 3 project I created in visual studio 2012.  I would like to run the dev server from the command line rather than the IDE (usually clicking on the green play/triangle button).

My goal is to run the local web server without having to open visual studio.  Any ideas?

Comment: It was my understanding that there is no longer a Visual Studio Development Server in VS2012. IIS Express is used instead. Is this what you're referring to?

Comment: If this is what runs your local instance when a user clicks on the build button in Visual Studio, then yes.  I'm interested in running iisexpress.exe from a command line exactly how visual studio runs it, ideally reusing some build artifact or script created by VS (I'm new to VS).  I want the command line = clicking the button in visual studio and not have to guess at any parameters.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Start your project from Visual Studio. Open Sysinternals Process Explorer and
navigate to your iisexpress instance. In properties - Image Tab - Command Line you get a hint of how you can call it.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe"  /config:"C:\Users\YourProfile\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config"  /site:"MvcApplication1(1)" /apppool:"Clr4IntegratedAppPool"
```

applicationhost.config will have your site in the history.